# Any idea on how can I count the number of elements that verify an "if" condition?

Tags: java

```
private static int chain(int n){
        int count = 0;
        while(n > 1){
            if(n % 2 == 0){
                count++; //the value is not stored
                return chain(n/2);
            }
            count++; //same thing
            return chain(3*n+1);
        }
        return count; //prints the initial value (0)
    }
}
```

I need to print the number of times the chain method reoccurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `count` variable from your method, and make it a static member of your class. And to prevent repeating yourlsef (DRY principle), you should increment the `count` variable at the top of your method.

```
private static int count = 0;

private static int chain(int n) {
    count++;

    while(n > 1) {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            return chain(n/2);
        }

        return chain(3*n+1);
    }

return count;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I believe the correct thing to do when writing a recursive method, would be to pass in a count variable.  This keeps the state of the method on the call stac rathern than in a class variable.  As someone else mentioned, this version would not be thread safe.

Comment: Although in the context of your question, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @aglassman I agree. A.R.S.'s answer describes very well how to do it ;)

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
public static int chain(int n) {
    return chain(n, 0);
}

private static int chain(int n, int count) {
    if (n > 1) {  // no need for a while-loop, it will never get past 1 iteration
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return chain(n / 2, count + 1);
        }
        return chain(3 * n + 1, count + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

To me, this seems cleaner than declaring a static field outside of the method, primarily because I wouldn't want to worry about having to reset the static field to 0 every time I call `chain`.

Comment: all this to get around static, geez =), nice answer though

Comment: Well, this is the master's approach. What I needed was something more simple that my mind can grasp without any further problems. Anyway, you have my vote.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand what you are asking. but if you want count to live outside of the method, instead of creating a local copy every time the method is called you can make it static.

```
static int count=0;
```

Comment: The other option is to make a return object for this method that has both n and count stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work too and doesn't use that ugly extra parameter.

I have adjusted the algorithm a little (putting `chain(3 * n + 1)` in an `else` part) on the assumption that this is actually an attempt at measuring the length of the [hailstone sequence of the Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hailstone_sequence). As originally stated it would merely stack overflow.

This code does indeed produce `111` when passed `27`.

```
private static int recursiveChain(int n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      return 1 + recursiveChain(n / 2);
    } else {
      return 1 + recursiveChain(3 * n + 1);
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And an iterative version looks surprisingly similar to the original question:

```
private static int iterativeChain(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  while (n > 1) {
    count += 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      n = n / 2;
    } else {
      n = 3 * n + 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```